# No usable Polish keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, xfce, internationalization

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with the XFCE desktop, all packages up to date.

I wanted to set up a keyboard layout for the Polish language (Polish uses the Roman alphabet, with a few additional characters like ą, ł, ż, etc). I went to the keyboard control panel, and under Polish I saw several options - all of them useless to me. One was for [Kashubian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashubian_language). One was the obsolete QWERTZ layout. Several variations of DVORAK. And one for Russian - I don't even know what it was doing there. What was missing was the de-facto standard layout, known as "polski programisty" ("Polish programmer's").

1. Is there a package that has the layout I want?
2. If not, how do I create my own layout? And where do I send the patch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take the default Polish layout (the one with the name `Polish`, with no further specification). This is the programmers layout.

[image]

EDIT: Alternatively, you can always do `setxkbmap -layout pl -variant basic` or just `setxkbmap -layout pl`, but that will not be kept across sessions.

Both XFCE and the default Unity shell use the same layouts, just with different interfaces. I guess the reason that XDE uses a tree structure is that all the different variants of the Polish layout are defined in the same file, `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pl`. By the way, it is a simple text file; creating your own layout is not hard.

Comment: I just said that I don't have this layout.

Comment: Also, I'm using XFCE. This screenshot is obviously from something else. Maybe this is a problem with XFCE only?

Comment: OK, I figured it out. The layout is there - it's just hiding in plain sight. In the control panel, where it's showing all the installed layouts, I don't see a list like you do - I see a tree. The root node of that tree says "Polish", so I assumed it was just a category, and couldn't be selected. But this is exactly what I have to select.

Comment: What is XDE? Do you mean XFCE?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem after update to `xbuntu 13.10`.
Selecting *Polish programmers* keyboard is even more counter intuitive, as the selection dialog shows a tree instead of a list.
Here the way to select Polish programmers keyboard:

[image: keyboard layout selection dialog]

This dialog is accessible via `Settings Manager > Keyboard > Layout > Add/Edit`